# How can I show loading icon or disable the button unitl logged in in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, loading

I want to show the loading icon when user click on login button until the login done. In my login.cshtm.cs file I have some code that handle and took time to logged in user. Now I want to show the loading icon to user when they click on login button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer the following sample:

```
<style type="text/css">

    .modal {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 998;
        height: 100% !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
        background-color: Black !important;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .loading {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>

<input type="button" value="Login" id="btnLogin" />

<div class="loading" align="center">
    Loading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <img src="https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/loader.gif" alt="" />
</div>
```

At the end of the above view page, add the following Scripts:

```
@section Scripts{
    @*Since I have already added the JQuery reference in the layout page, there is no need to add JQuery reference here.
        If you didn't add the JQuery reference before, please remember to add the JQuery reference first*@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var modal, loading;
        function ShowProgress() {
            modal = document.createElement("DIV");
            modal.className = "modal";
            document.body.appendChild(modal);
            loading = document.getElementsByClassName("loading")[0];
            loading.style.display = "block";
            var top = Math.max(window.innerHeight / 2 - loading.offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max(window.innerWidth / 2 - loading.offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.style.top = top + "px";
            loading.style.left = left + "px";
        };

        function HideProgress() {
            document.body.removeChild(modal);
            loading.style.display = "none";
        };
        $(function () {
            $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
                //show the loading image
                ShowProgress();

                //using JQuery ajax to call the event handler and login,
                //and then, in the Ajax success function, call the HideProgress function to hide the loading image.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    HideProgress();
                }, 5000);
            });
        });
    </script> 
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using jquery like how we use other web application.

Here's a working spinet:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}


.loader {
 display: none;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


 .loading {
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 border-top-color: #1ecd97;
 border-left-color: #1ecd97;
 animation: spin 1s infinite ease-in;
 }

 @keyframes spin {
 0% {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
 }

 100% {
 transform: rotate(360deg);
 }
}

<button type="submit" class="sbtn btn btn-secondary btn-c" onclick="spinner()">
  Log in</button>
 <div class="loader">
 <div class="loading">
 </div>
 </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
   function spinner() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[0].style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
```